# Updating a UILabel in a UITableViewCell in realtime

Tags: ios, uitableview

**Please see edit below**

I'm trying to update the text in a label in a `UITableViewCell` in real time to reflect the elapsed time since the cell was selected via `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

The symptom of the problem is that the label remains blank.

Here is the code in my `updateTime` method:

```
-(void)updateTime
{


    //Which calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //Gets the componentized interval from the most recent time an activity was tapped until now
    NSDateComponents *components= [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:currentTimedActivity.startTime toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSInteger hours = [components hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
    NSInteger seconds =[components second];
//    
    if(!seconds)
    {
        [timer invalidate];

    }
    //Converts the components to a string and displays it in the duration label
    cellLabelTempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds];
    self.durationLabel.text = cellLabelTempText;

    NSLog(@"The label should be reading %02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds);
    NSLog(@"cellLabelTempText is reading %@",cellLabelTempText);
    NSLog(@"The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.");
    NSLog(@"The durationLabel is actually showing %@",self.durationLabel.text);


    [self.myTableView reloadData];

}
```

My NSLog instructions yield the following:

```
2014-03-12 14:48:57.433 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The label should be reading 00:00:00
2014-03-12 14:48:57.434 WMDGx[69802:a0b] cellLabelTempText is reading 00:00:00
2014-03-12 14:48:57.435 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.
2014-03-12 14:48:57.435 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel is actually showing (null)
2014-03-12 14:48:57.933 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The label should be reading 00:00:01
2014-03-12 14:48:57.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] cellLabelTempText is reading 00:00:01
2014-03-12 14:48:57.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.
2014-03-12 14:48:57.935 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel is actually showing (null)
2014-03-12 14:48:58.933 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The label should be reading 00:00:02
2014-03-12 14:48:58.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] cellLabelTempText is reading 00:00:02
2014-03-12 14:48:58.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.
2014-03-12 14:48:58.935 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel is actually showing (null)
2014-03-12 14:48:59.933 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The label should be reading 00:00:03
2014-03-12 14:48:59.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] cellLabelTempText is reading 00:00:03
2014-03-12 14:48:59.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.
2014-03-12 14:48:59.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel is actually showing (null)
2014-03-12 14:49:00.933 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The label should be reading 00:00:04
2014-03-12 14:49:00.933 WMDGx[69802:a0b] cellLabelTempText is reading 00:00:04
2014-03-12 14:49:00.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.
2014-03-12 14:49:00.934 WMDGx[69802:a0b] The durationLabel is actually showing (null)
```

I'm stumped because the temporary string `cellLabelTempText` is updating correctly, and `self.durationLabel.text` is equal to `cellLabelTempText`, yet registers as `(null)` in the log.

All help much appreciated!

**Edit per @rmaddy's suggestion in comments below (please read):**

Since my `self.durationLabel` is showing `nil`, I tried connecting to an IBOutlet, but get this error:

```
... /WMDGx/MainStoryboard.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x7ff6a28f8560  <IBProxyObject: 0x7ff6a28f55e0> => durationLabel => <IBUILabel: 0x7ff6a28f34a0>>
```

This gives a good indication about where the problem lies, but if the whole thing depends on an IBOutlet, and I can't hook it up to one, where do I go from here?

Thanks!

Comment: It appears that `self.durationLabel` is `nil`. Verify that.

Comment: There you go then. Fix that and you'll get further. If you are using Interface Builder, fix your connection to the outlet for the label.

Comment: I'm using storyboard. I tried connecting the label via an IBOutlet, but got an error saying the compiler couldn't make the connection. I researched that and read an answer that you can't connect an outlet to a label in a prototype cell. Did I misunderstand?

Comment: I've never used Interface Builder or storyboards so someone else is going to have to help. Now that you know the issue, you should redo your question to focus on this issue.

Comment: Just tried it again, got this error: .../WMDGx/MainStoryboard.storyboard: Couldn't compile connection: <IBCocoaTouchOutletConnection:0x7ff6a28f8560  <IBProxyObject: 0x7ff6a28f55e0> => durationLabel => <IBUILabel: 0x7ff6a28f34a0>>

Comment: Good idea, rmaddy. Will do, and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is that you don't have a single durationLabel; you have as many as you have cells in your table. (The error specifically is trying to connect a tableCell prototype to a specific label).  I'd suggest subclassing UITableviewCell, adding a durationLabel label and property (which can be linked to a prototype cell), and putting this timer code inside that subclass.

Something like this:

In your tableViewController:

```
//At the top:
#import "PTCell.h"

//replace didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
-(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    PTCell * cell = (PTCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell startTimer];
}
```

PTCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PTCell : UITableViewCell;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *durationLabel;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSDate * startTime;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSTimer * timer;

-(void) startTimer;
-(void) stopTimer;

@end
```

PTCell.m:

```
#import "PTCell.h"

@implementation PTCell

-(void)updateTime {

    //Which calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    //Gets the componentized interval from the most recent time an activity was tapped until now
    NSDateComponents *components= [calendar components:NSHourCalendarUnit|NSMinuteCalendarUnit|NSSecondCalendarUnit fromDate:self.startTime toDate:[NSDate date] options:0];

    NSInteger hours = [components hour];
    NSInteger minutes = [components minute];
    NSInteger seconds =[components second];
    //
    if(!seconds)
    {
        [self.timer invalidate];

    }
    //Converts the components to a string and displays it in the duration label
    NSString * cellLabelTempText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds];
    self.durationLabel.text = cellLabelTempText;

    NSLog(@"The label should be reading %02i:%02i:%02i",hours,minutes,seconds);
    NSLog(@"cellLabelTempText is reading %@",cellLabelTempText);
    NSLog(@"The durationLabel should read the same, as they are equal.");
    NSLog(@"The durationLabel is actually showing %@",self.durationLabel.text);

}

-(void) startTimer {
    [self stopTimer];
    self.startTime = [NSDate date];
    self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateTime) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) stopTimer {
    [self.timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;
}

@end
```

Comment: Oh, and why are you invalidating if seconds are zero?

Comment: Hey, thanks @mack! Give me a couple of hours to try this out and I'll let you know how it works!

Comment: I assume you meant didSelectRowAtIndexPath rather than didSelectItemAtIndexPath? And cellForRowAtIndexPath instead of cellForItemAtIndexPath?

Comment: Sorry, yes. I've been using all collectionviews lately, and tried to translate on the fly!

Comment: If you'll indulge me, my only experience with creating cells is in the storyboard, and when I tried to use your code (after changing the wording) the whole place lit up with errors. I know how to connect an IBoutlet in storyboard, but not how to do it in code.

Comment: No problem.  Actually, you're not connecting it in code in this case.  If you've created those two files (`PTCell.h` and `.m`), then all you do is change your tableviewcell prototype in IB to be custom class `PTCell`.  Then you connect the cell's `durationLabel` (that I think you already have) to `PTCell.h`'s `durationLabel`.  Your errors are probably due to needing to add `#import "PTCell.h"` at the top of your TableViewController.  See above

Comment: Ok, I think I've caught up now, but will need some time to sort out some names, with all the changes. OK to report back tomorrow? Thanks!

Comment: Oh, I should mention delete your durationLabel property in the TableViewController (and updateTime method).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49621/discussion-between-tim-jones-and-mackworth)